# Forced user logout in case of internal errors in cakephp3.0

Tags: php, cakephp, error-handling, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp 3.0 ,In my application I want forced user logout or clear session in case if any internal error occurs,How can I accomplish it. Can I make any changes in the error controller and will it able to catch the specific internal errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP uses the `ErrorController` to render HTTP responses for both unhandled exceptions and fatal errors. Keep in mind that it's also used for 404 not found exceptions.

You can logout the user in `ErrorController` in the `beforeFilter` event, and render the error message as normal. Afterwards their session will have ended.

I give you a warning. The `ErrorController` should be kept as simple as possible. Should not perform heavy logic. The reason is very simple. If you generate a fatal error inside `ErrorController` it creates an endless loop.

Most people configure their `AuthComponent` in their base `AppController` which you should never extend as the base class for `ErrorController`.

That means you have to configure the `AuthComponent` separately in your `ErrorController` and hope it never fails and you keep the configuration consistent with what you have in `AppController`.

If you go that route. Also wrap your code in a `try/catch` block to prevent exceptions from being thrown from inside the `ErrorController`.

For example;

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    try {
        $this->Auth->logout();
    }catch(\Exception $ex) {
        // prevent endless loop
    }
}
```

Alternative perform a 302 redirect:

It's better to keep `ErrorController` as vanilla as possible and not load the `AuthComponent` inside it. I assume you have a controller already set up for logging users in and out. Add a new route for that controller called "forced_out", and then redirect the URL to that route when there is an uncaught exception. Inside the action for "forced_out" you can log the current user out.

Create a new error handler class like this.

```
class ForceOutErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {
    protected function _displayException($exception)
    {
         // restore the old handler
         (new ErrorHandler(Configure::read('Error')))->register();

         throw new RedirectException(Router::url([
            'controller'=>'Users',
            'action'=>'forced_out'
         ));
    }
}
```

Now register that error class only when a user is signed in. You can do this in the `beforeFilter` of your `AppController` like this:

```
public function beforeFlter(Event $event) {
     if($this->Auth->user()) {
        (new ForceOutErrorHandler(Configure::read('Error')))->register()
     }
}
```

> Note: I'm not sure if CakePHP will catch the redirect exception from inside the error handler like that or not. You might have to use `header(); die()` as a last try.

Comment: I think it will handle every error and calls logout function for every error. I want to call logout function only for the internal errors (500 series erors)

Comment: In Error Controller is it possible for us to identify what type of error  occurs. Because it is correctly showing the error pages based on the type of error

Comment: @RosaMystica `ErrorController` renders a view without calling an action. So the only way to get to the data is in the `beforeRender` event. All the data is in the `$this->viewVars` of the controller. You can check for the code like this `$code = $this->viewVars['code'];` and see if it's 500.